# Error when Get files from specific URL SharePoint C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I have problem with sharepoint when I try to get all file in a specific url.
I've try get files in url

> https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/

It's work, but when want to get files in url

> https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Processing/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewid=b59c189a-26e1-42ff-b0b8-0e5aefc93734&id=%2Fsites%2FProcessing%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral%2FApp2020

It returns error ***Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: File Not Found.***

This is the first time I work with sharepoint. I'm look forward to receive your help. Many thanks.

Here is my code:

```
var targetSiteURL = new Uri("https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Processing/");
ClientContext cxt = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
cxt.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
                    
var list = cxt.Web.GetList("/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewid=b59c189a-26e1-42ff-b0b8-0e5aefc93734&id=%2Fsites%2FProcessing%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral%2FApp2020");

var listItems = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
cxt.Load(listItems,
items => items.Include(
item => item.File));
cxt.ExecuteQuery();                    
this.lblMessage.Text = listItems.First().File.Name.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
var list =cxt.Web.GetList("sites/Processing/Shared%20Documents")
```

To get the specific file:

```
File file = cxt.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/Processing/Shared%20Documents/test.doc");
cxt.Load(file);
cxt.ExecuteQuery(); 
Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: It returns the same error :(

Comment: if i want to get file from specific file `%2Fsites%2FProcessing%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral%2FApp2020` then what should I do in that code?

Comment: Check my updated answer,

Comment: It has not worked. And still returns file not found :(

Comment: when I set `var targetSiteURL = new Uri("https://mycompany.sharepoint.com");` and `var list =cxt.Web.GetList("/Shared%20Documents")` then it worked, but when I set `var list =cxt.Web.GetList("/sites/Processing/Shared%20Documents")` then it return file not found since that

Comment: It;s the relative URL of the library. The site https://mycompany.sharepoint.com is the root site collection, use cxt.Web.GetList("/Shared%20Documents") would work. If your sites url is like https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/test, you need to use "/sites/test/Shared%20Documents".

Comment: thank you very much, I pass this error, But how can I get file in subfolder inside `/sites/s01/Shared%20Documents`? I'd tried this url `/sites/s01/Shared%20Documents/General/App` but it still return file in url `/sites/s01/Shared%20Documents` :(

Comment: For folders, you need to use cxt.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl() method. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee539339(v=office.15)

Comment: I'm done, Thanks for you help. Thank you very much